# KivyMD installation error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

I tried to install kivymd using `pip3 install kivymd`, but got error:

```
/tmp/pip-build-46hjob8h/kivy/kivy/include/gl_redirect.h:72:13: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
 #   include <GL/gl.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
 error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems that I have to install GL-related libs on my system.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install OpenGL headers using:

```
sudo apt install libglew-dev
```